# Running Devstack script ./stack.sh

Tags: python, openstack, devstack

I am new to OpenStack and I am facing an error while installing openstack using devstack script.

I followed the normal steps:

1. git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git
2. cd devstack
3. ./stack.sh

But while running the script with the command `./stack.sh`
script stopped due to the following error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   prettytable>0.7 (from versions: 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.7,
>      0.7.1, 0.7.2)   No distributions matching the version for prettytable>0.7

Can someone please help me to solve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the file `devstack/tools/fixup_stuff.sh`, change the `0.7` to `0.7.*`

Comment: now there is following error

No distributions matching the version for SQLAlchemy<=0.8.99,<=0.9.99,>=0.8.4,>=0.9.7 (from keystone===2015.1.dev190.gea4fcec)

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you are trying to reuse an older devstack installation, as this bug should have been fixed a couple of weeks ago.

However, running stack.sh by default does not update the source repos once they exist, so you can either add "RECLONE=yes" to your config or go manually through the repos in /opt/stack and update them.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove python-prettytable if you have it installed through apt-get
  `$ sudo apt-get purge python-prettytable`
- Upgrade prettytable through pip
  `$ pip install --upgrade 'prettytable>=0.7'`
- Change prettytable requirement in tools/fixup_stuff.sh line 78
  `pip_install 'prettytable>=0.7'`
- Run stack.sh again

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered the same problem, for solving this I have done the following:

1. pip uninstall setuptools
2. pip install prettytable

then again run the ./stack.sh it will work.

The error happens because the setuptools does not allow the deprecated version of prettytable to install.

Answer (score 0):

This might be compatibility issue. Better go with stable versions of devstack.

```
git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack -b stable/<version_name>
```

For example:

```
git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack -b stable/pike
```